# AJAX XML reply node value iteration

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I would really appreciate to get your help on this, as I can't seem to detect and solve the problem I'm having with an AJAX functionality on a site that I'm currently developing.

I have a `webform` that makes an asynchronous call to a handler (`.ashx`) that delivers a XML response that is later processed by a Javascript client-side function that places it's contents into the user-interface.

I'm attaching an example of the response generated by my handler, and what I would like to know is how can I get all the `<body>` element `innerHTML` (with the text and child nodes) contents to append it to a `<span>` element on the user-interface. Can anyone help me out with this?

XML Response returned by the handler (checked via Firebug):

```
<message>
    <content>
        <messageId>2</messageId>
        <from>Barack Obama</from>
        <fromMail>barack.obama@whitehouse.gov</fromMail>
        <subject>Yes, we can... get World Peace</subject> 
        <body>Hello, dear citizen. I'm sending you this message to invite you to join us! <a href="http://www.whitehouse.gov">Test link</a> Thank you for your time.</body>
    </content>
</message>
```

Client-side Javascript function to affect the user-interface `innerHTML` property with the data returned via AJAX:

```
function GetMessageContentsCallback(args, resp) {
    //XML Parser
    try {
        //Internet Explorer
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(resp);
    }
    catch (e) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(resp, "text/xml");
    }
    var msgReply = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('message')[0];
    var ajaxRespondeBodyInnerHTML = msgReply.getElementsByTagName(body)[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    //this currently only delivers inner text content, without the <a href... bit and subsequent text
    document.getElementById("bodySpan").innerHTML = ajaxRespondeBodyInnerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you have a syntax error.  I tested and found the problem is with this line as expected:

```
var ajaxRespondeBodyInnerHTML = msgReply.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

**`body`** is not in quotes.

See http://jsbin.com/ufubo/edit for a working example.

Edit: Also, if you want to have HTML in your XML, you need to nest your content in CDATA tags.  I've updated the example to show this.

Edit: I've update the example *and* saved it...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, your solution doesn't seem to accomplish what I want, as it doesn't show the "<a href=..." and the subsequent piece of text (prior to the anchor element).
What I want is to show everything (all the content) of the "<body>" element of my XML AJAX response, not only the "<body>" node value.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, but your solution doesn't seem to accomplish what I want, as I would like to display ALL node and child nodes content on the placeholder. In the end I would like to have this: placeholder.innerHTML = "Hello, dear citizen. I'm sending you this message to invite you to join us! <a href='http://www.whitehouse.gov'>Test link</a> Thank you for your time."
Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Like Justin said, you need to wrap the body in CDATA as the body node contains more XML.

Comment: Sorry, it appears that i didn't save the changes to my example at jsbin.  Try again, it now works as you've described.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like

```
var ajaxRespondeBodyInnerHTML = msgReply.getElementsByTagName(body)[0].text;
```

or

```
var ajaxRespondeBodyInnerHTML = msgReply.getElementsByTagName(body)[0].innerHTML;
```

that might hopefully grab everything inside?

(it's been awhile since I've worked with xml returned via ajax)

Comment: None of your suggestions seem to work. However, thank you for your reply.